# Count value to some id in table using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like

```
ID,"url","used_at","active_seconds"
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com/videos168693045?section=all",2016-03-01 10:18:45,4
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com",2016-03-01 10:18:49,2
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com/feed",2016-03-01 10:18:51,2
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com/audios291781172",2016-03-01 10:18:53,2
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com/audios291781172?q=РўРёРјСѓСЂ%20Р“Р°С‚РёСЏС‚СѓР»Р»РёРЅ%20%7C%20Р§РµСЃС‚РЅС‹Р№%20-%20РЈР»РµС‚Р°Р№%20РїРѕР»РЅР°СЏ%20РІРµСЂСЃРёСЏ",2016-03-01 10:18:55,6
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com/audios291781172?q=РўРёРјСѓСЂ%20Р“Р°С‚РёСЏС‚СѓР»Р»РёРЅР§РµСЃС‚РЅС‹Р№%20-%20РЈР»РµС‚Р°Р№%20РїРѕР»РЅР°СЏ%20РІРµСЂСЃРёСЏ",2016-03-01 10:19:01,2
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com/audios291781172?q=РўРёРјСѓСЂ%20Р“Р°С‚РёСЏС‚СѓР»Р»РёРЅ%20Р§РµСЃС‚РЅС‹Р№%20-%20РЈР»РµС‚Р°Р№%20РїРѕР»РЅР°СЏ%20РІРµСЂСЃРёСЏ",2016-03-01 10:19:03,4
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb,"vk.com/audios168693045?section=all",2016-03-01 10:19:07,2
```

I need to count `id` in url that include `audios`.
Desire output:

```
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb: 291781172 - 4, 168693045 - 1, etc
```

I don't know how can I get `id` after `audio` and count that.

```
data = pd.read_csv("get_id.csv")
data_name = pd.read_excel("name.xlsx")
names_panel = data_name['Names']
urls = data['url']
ids = data['ID']
for url in urls:
    if 'audios' in url:
        print url
```

Comment: IIUC then you could add a new column with the extracted user id and call `value_counts` on this: `df['user_id'] = df['url'].str.extract(r'audios(\d+)?')
df['user_id'].value_counts()`

Comment: If I need to print first `ID` from table `d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb` and next count `id` from `vk.com`, to know, how often this `user` saw `audio`. This code count `id` after `audio` to all `list` of `url`, but I need to count it to every `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print pd.concat([df['ID'], df['url'].str.extract('(?P<count>audios)(?P<digit>\d+)')], axis=1).groupby(['ID', 'digit']).count()

                                            count
ID                               digit           
d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb 168693045      1
                                 291781172      4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And can you say, if I want get count of `ID` who visit `vk.com`, what should I do? I Know, that I can get all `ID` `df['ID'].nunique()`. I don't know how can I add condition about `vk.com`

Comment: @hellmoore Try `print df['url'].groupby([df['ID'], df['url'].str.contains('vk.com')]).count().reset_index(name='visit')` first, and add `['ID'].count()` to it and try again to retrieve the number what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `ID` and new column `no` with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df[['no']] = df.url.str.extract(r'audios(\d+)?', expand=False)
print df

print df.groupby(['ID', 'no']).size().reset_index(name='count')
                                 ID         no  count
0  d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb  168693045      1
1  d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb  291781172      4
```

Or without creating new column:

```
print df.groupby([df.ID, df.url.str.extract(r'audios(\d+)?', expand=False)])
        .size().reset_index(name='count')
                                 ID        url  count
0  d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb  168693045      1
1  d684cd5f0189ab49c391c2b7bcbac0cb  291781172      4
```

I little improve [su79eu7k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157915/2901002) answer (add `as_index=False` for return `DataFrame` and remove warning by add `expand=False`) and then compare solutions:

**Timing**:

```
In [152]: %timeit pd.concat([df['ID'], df['url'].str.extract('(?P<count>audios)(?P<digit>\d+)', expand=False)], axis=1).groupby(['ID', 'digit'], as_index=False).count()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.5 ms per loop

In [153]: %timeit df.groupby([df.ID, df.url.str.extract(r'audios(\d+)?', expand=False)]).size().reset_index(name='count')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.92 ms per loop
```

Comment: opps, you are right. answer was edited. Thank you, `EdChum`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-pythonic way to do it (using loops).

First IIUC the numbers you are trying to get always have the same length, am I right? then just do a list out of your url, select what you want, and create a string back out of it.

```
ids = df.ID.unique()
for identity in ids:
    my_list = []
    for url in urls:
        if 'audios' in url:
            my_list.append(''.join(list(url)[13:22]))
    for number in set(my_list):
        print(str(identity) + ': ' +number +': '+ str(my_list.count(number)))
```